# Python pyvmomi VMware API - how to convert a VM to template?

Tags: python, api, vmware, vsphere, pyvmomi

I was looking at a solution to convert a VMware vsphere VM to a template using any of Ansible modules and failed as it seems `vmware_guest` (using pyvmomi) failed to to that.

So, I started investigating the alternatives; it seems the direct `pyvmomi` python script can send the API towards vCenter and it will do the task - though I haven't found any of examples, unfortunately.

I have read the VMware API documentation It states that the `VirtualMachineConfigSpec` should be used as well as:

> "A virtual machine template is a virtual machine that cannot be
>   powered on and that is not associated with a resource pool. You can
>   convert any powered off virtual machine to a template by calling
>   VirtualMachine.MarkAsTemplate. After the conversion, the original
>   virtual machine no longer exists."

Can I ask anyone to help me develop a very basic script that connects to vCenter, finds the given VM and converts it to template?

Answer (score 2):

First download and execute some of the samples found in the [pyvmomi-community-samples](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples) (preferably in a [python virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)).

Then use any sample which retrieves a `vim.VirtualMachine` object (e.g. [add_disk_to_vm.py](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/add_disk_to_vm.py)), and after the `vm` object is retrieved, call `vm.MarkAsTemplate()`.